# Who calculate steal time in virtualization? How guest os knows that it's time is stolen?

Tags: linux-kernel, virtualization, qemu, kvm, hypervisor

I have installed qemu in my laptop which has KVM enabled. I have installed Linux VM on the top of qemu. I have seen steal time in top command. I want to know

1. How the steal time is calculated?
2. Is it calculated in host OS or guest OS?
3. How guest knows about this stolen time?
4. When guest os knows about this stolen time?
5. Is this something related with the structure in Linux struct kvm_steal_time?